# Choosing between glMatrix, Sylvester and CanvasMatrix?

Tags: javascript, webgl

Finally, I decided to make my own WebGL 3D engine from the ground up, I begin tutorials from http://www.khronos.org/webgl/ and http://learningwebgl.com and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebGL

But problem is that each tutorial used/recommend different library for Matrix calculations, so I'm confused!

- khronos recommend CanvasMatrix (but now they switch to J3DI.js from Apple ?)
- Mozilla recommend Sylvester all the way!
- Learningwebgl.com recommend glMatrix

Question is: Which one is well suited for 3D WebGL Applications, Charts and Games? (both performance and usability matters)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look at http://greggman.github.io/webgl-matrix-benchmarks/matrix_benchmark.html

I use glMatrix, and it works fine. The API is a bit weird.

```
var in = vec3.create([1, 2, 3]);

//overwrite 'in' in-place
vec3.scale(in, 2);

//write output to a different vector
var out = vec3.create();
vec3.scale(in, 2, out);
```

Or for glMatrix 2

```
var in = vec3.fromValues(1, 2, 3);

//overwrite 'in' in-place
vec3.scale(in, in, 2);

//write output to a different vector
var out = vec3.create();
vec3.scale(out, in, 2);
```

But it's fast, it supports the operations I want, and it's straightforward. Additionally, The source is very understandable.

I have no experience with the others, though.

**Update:**

There are benchmarks of more libraries available at http://stepheneb.github.io/webgl-matrix-benchmarks/matrix_benchmark.html. In Chrome on my Mac, Closure wins pretty handily. In Chrome on my PC, it's much more of a toss-up. I'm still using glMatrix for now, since it lives in a single Javascript file.

Comment: A pity that they don't benchmark against numeric.js and Sylvester. According to [the numeric.js benchmark](http://www.numericjs.com/benchmark.html), Sylvester is actually faster than Google Closure for 3x3 (and higher) matrix by matrix multiplications, at least on my system (WinXP/32 with Chrome 20).

Comment: I [just added Sylvester](https://github.com/feklee/webgl-matrix-benchmarks) to the benchmark (pull request pending). Sylvester is *slow*. Why is it faster than Closure in the [Numeric Javascript benchmark](http://www.numericjs.com/benchmark.html)? The answer: That benchmark tests Closure's generic matrix functions, not those dedicated to WebGL.

Comment: well, in glMatrix 2.2.0 vec3.create does not take a parameter and creating one as shown here will create a vec3 of zero length, but vec3.fromValues(1,2,3) will work